# Force shutdown mac via terminal

Tags: terminal, shutdown

I know I can shutdown a mac via terminal using

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

But that is a graceful shutdown how can I force it to immediately die (I know this is bad practice)

ditto for rebooting

there doesn't appear to be an argument for --force or such.

Comment: Have a look at `reboot -q`. This isn't a graceful shutdown. See the manpages for `reboot`, `halt` and `shutdown` for more information. Why do you not want a graceful halt or reboot?

Comment: `man shutdown` has (as any other man page) a `SEE ALSO` section which might be useful in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [JRFerguson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/396133/jrferguson)

the answer was

```
sudo halt -q
```